# Incrementation not working in function

Tags: php

Increment $i not working in function it returns 1++

```
function show7days()
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE dateuploaded >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) order by visits desc LIMIT 7");
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $name = $row[2];
        $descr = $row[3];
        $img = $row[4];
        $i=1;
        echo "<p align=\"center\">$i.$i++<a href=\"/movie/".($row[2])."\"><img src=\"/movie/".($img)."\ height=\"30\" width=\"30\";></a><br><a href=\"/movie/$row[2]\">$name</a></p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: No sure what you are trying to accomplish!

Comment: $i = 1 place this out of while loop start

Comment: You just said it, place $i outside the while loop!

Comment: Yes I'm stupid now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Every time you will get same value because you are initializing inside the loop. And you have missed the quotes.

```
$i=1;// keep this outside.
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $name = $row[2];
    $descr = $row[3];
    $img = $row[4];

    echo "<p align=\"center\">".$i++."<a href=\"/movie/".($row[2])."\"><img src=\"/movie/".($img)."\ height=\"30\" width=\"30\";></a><br><a href=\"/movie/$row[2]\">$name</a></p>";
                              ^     ^//missed the quotes aswell
  }
```

Comment: @1mnumb1 Glad it helped you:) Accept the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $i=1;
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE dateuploaded >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) order by visits desc LIMIT 7");
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $name = $row[2];
    $descr = $row[3];
    $img = $row[4];
            echo "<p align=\"center\">$i.$i++<a href=\"/movie/".($row[2])."\"><img src=\"/movie/".($img)."\ height=\"30\" width=\"30\";></a><br><a href=\"/movie/$row[2]\">$name</a></p>";
      }
    }

It may solve your problem
```